# Python: Load CSV, first column as row names, first row as column names

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I want to load a CSV file using Python2.7, in which the first row contains column names and the first column contains row names.

My CSV file looks like beneath.

```
  A  B  C  D
a 1. 2. 3. 4. 
b 5. 6. 7. 8.
```

I don't know how to do that with numpy or pandas. Can someone enlighten me ? Thanks !

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Data frame or numpy array?

Comment: I would like to get a data frame. I want to access each matrix element by its column name and row name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pd.read_csv`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjjlPWg4MTMAhXBjywKHZpNCB0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.read_csv.html&usg=AFQjCNE1cTwGgwS3WFrM8PRoP9YzTbLAGA&sig2=Cj_KPxrM65-Veg08IHJUmw&bvm=bv.121421273,d.bGg) with regex separator `\s+`:

```
import pandas as pd

In [4]: pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+')
Out[4]:
     A    B    C    D
a  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
b  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Or you could use `delim_whitespace` argument for that:

```
In [5]: pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
Out[5]:
     A    B    C    D
a  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
b  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `s\+` - arbitrary whitespace:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""A B C D
a 1. 2. 3. 4.
b 5. 6. 7. 8."""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
print df
     A    B    C    D
a  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
b  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Comment: It works, thank you ! Up-voted ! Also thanks for the link of the docs.